# Why is -9 considered bigger than 1?

Tags: c#, linq

The dataset I have is :

```
Name                        Order        ID 
Summary                     1            147
Software Functionality     -9            211
```

I have this LINQ query:

```
string value = projectA.OrderByDescending(a => a.Order)
                       .ThenBy(a => a.Name)
                       .ToList()
                       .First()
                       .ID
                       .ToString();
```

The answer I get is 211, but I think the answer should be 147. Why does this happen?

Note: the `Order` field is of type `string`.

Comment: Is `Order` a numeric or string type?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter as `-` is `chr(45)`.

Comment: Sorry, just a copy paste error, it is a string.

Comment: @DStanley It is stored as "1" and "-9" in the list

Comment: A quick look at [this ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) shows that "-" comes before "1", as Juan Lopes has intimated.  Therefore, an ASCII sort order will have "-9" before "1".

Comment: @BobRodes I don't know what point you're trying to make. 1) The OP is using `OrderByDescending()` which would list 1 before -9. 2) The gotcha regarding the string comparison is described in Jeroen Vannevel's answer (i.e. CompareOptions).

Comment: @itsme86 Careless observation on my part.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the output you have because your `Order` is a `string`. As proof, this sample will show that you get the correct output when it's an integer:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<Project>() { new Project() { Order = 1, Id = 147, Name = "Summary" }, new Project() { Order = -9, Id = 211, Name = "Software Functionality" } };
    int value= list.OrderByDescending(a => a.Order).ThenBy(a => a.Name).ToList().First().Id;
    Console.WriteLine (value);
}

public class Project 
{
    public int Order {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

> However, in case you do need it as a string: why doesn't it work like this?

Take a look at the [`CompareOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions.aspx) enum. More specificically: `CompareOptions.IgnoreSymbols`.

> Indicates that the string comparison must **ignore** symbols, such as white-space characters, punctuation, currency symbols, the percent sign, **mathematical symbols**, the ampersand, and so on. This is also explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/116701/String-Compare-bug-with-negative-number-string).

This essentially makes your `-9` a `9`.

You can bypass this easily by creating your own comparer and passing it what you need:

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x,string y)
    {
        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

which can be used as

```
new[] {"1", "-9"}.OrderByDescending(x => x, new CustomComparer())
```

Comment: Note: I don't have the time to search after what `CompareOptions` are used by default so feel free to edit it in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reconstruct your issue. Here is my code (LinqPad), which works properly:

```
void Main()
{
    List<ProgramA> progs = new List<ProgramA>{
        new ProgramA("Summary", 1, 147),
        new ProgramA("Software Functionality", -9, 211)
        };

    int value= progs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Order).ThenBy(a => a.Name).ToList().First().ID;

    value.Dump();

}

// Define other methods and classes here
class ProgramA
{
    private string sName = string.Empty;
    private int iOrder = 0;
    private int iID = 0;

    public ProgramA(string _Name, int _Order, int _ID)
    {
        sName = _Name;
        iOrder = _Order;
        iID = _ID;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get {return sName;}
        set {sName = value;}
    }

    public int Order
    {
        get {return iOrder;}
        set {iOrder = value;}
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get {return iID;}
        set {iID = value;}
    }
}
```

returns: **147**

**[EDIT]**

*@DStanley It is stored as "1" and "-9" in the list –  user1989 6 mins ago*

If *Order* is stored as string value, you can try to convert it into integer:

```
    int value= progs.OrderByDescending(a => Convert.ToInt32(a.Order)).ThenBy(a => a.Name).ToList().First().ID;
```

Comment: Because it does not answer the question and does not replicate the problem. His `Order` field is of type `string`.

Comment: A OP's comment about *Order* field is a string value has been added when i wrote my answer. Please, see my answer after edit.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, so why your answer is better than mine? You provided the same solution as mine! BTW: in the same time!

Answer (score -3):

string value= projectA.OrderByDescending(a => a.Order).ThenBy(a => a.Name).ToList().First().ID.ToString();

OrderByDescending => Orders 
Output - -9, 1

Select First element 
- 9 = 211. Logic is correct.